# How to edit JTable, which was created by pallette components?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created a form with some tables and I want to add columns and rows to each of them. I am doing it using this code in a constructor (example for one of the tables):

```
MainWindow(){
    TableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel)table1.getModel();
    ((DefaultTableModel) model1).addColumn("r1");
    ((DefaultTableModel) model1).addColumn("r2");
```

But it doesn't work. I see just empty tables and nothing changes: 
[Final window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMbWx.png).

### Full code is here:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class MainWindow {
    private JPanel jpanel1;
    private JButton button1;
    private JButton button2;
    private JTable table1;
    private JTable table2;
    private JTable table3;
    private JTable table4;
    private JTable table5;
    private JTable table6;
    private JTable table7;
    private JTable table8;
    private JTable table9;
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JList list1;

    MainWindow(){
        TableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel)table1.getModel();
        ((DefaultTableModel) model1).addColumn("r1");
        ((DefaultTableModel) model1).addColumn("r2");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainWindow");
        frame.setContentPane(new MainWindow().jpanel1);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1000, 900);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The form with components:
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Nov.png).
Thank you for any advice!

Comment: *"I see just empty tables"* I just see a `NullPointerException`. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You see this exception because you haven't a form MainWindow.form. I don't know, how to add it to here. It is not a code, just tables and other components, which I added by hand from the Swing palette.

Comment: Is the table inside a `JScrollPane`? Otherwise the column headers will not be shown.

Comment: *"Thank you for your answer."* It's a comment, not an answer. *"You see this exception because you haven't a form MainWindow.form."* That's why I suggest you post an MCVE / SSCCE. Please follow and read links to both documents.

Comment: It's inside JPanel

Comment: *"It's inside JPanel "* Tip: Add @PrasadKarunagoda (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. BTW - when can we expect to see the MCVE / SSCCE that would have answered that question without anyone needing to ask?